# Can I assign the template type name dynamically?

Tags: c++, templates

```
//define the type and its argument
struct Argument
{
    char* name;
    int age;
    double height;
}
struct typeAndArg
{
    QWidget *instance;
    Argument args;
}

template<class T>
createPerson(Argument arg)
{
//an API which do similiar case but only the typename T is differnt, the //argument can also be specify according to //differnt type
    ....
    T* w = new T(arg.name,arg.age,arg.height);
    .....
    return w;
};

main()
{
    QMap<QWidget*,Argument> myMap;
    QPushButton a;
    QCheckBox b;
    QLineEdit c;
    
    myMap[&a] = Argument("me", 18, 111.11);
    myMap[&b] = Argument("you", 25, 222.22);
    myMap[&c] = Argument("him", 67, 333.33);

    for(auto iter = myMap.begin();iter != myMap.end(); ++iter){
        createPerson(decltype(iter.key)),iter.value());//<--I just //want to use one line here, let me decide what type and argument to //pass to the API
    }   
}
```

the key question is here: I want to use a single for loop to do all the things in one line, don't want to specify typename always, because the map maybe very long and random order, I don't want to call the API mutiple times

Comment: please post a [mcve]. The code you did post is bogus, starting from line 1 it is full of syntax errors and makes no sense

Comment: Template arguments must be known at compile time.

Comment: what is `variable`? Maybe you are looking for `decltype(variable)` but it is really hard to tell. `typeid` is very likely the wrong tool

Comment: *"why I alwasy couldn't pass the editing? do you set too much limit for our editing?"* -- possibly because you edited the post to contain almost all code and very little text, which is a strong indicator of a low-quality question. Contributing to this is the fact that you ended your code block incorrectly (two backticks instead of three), so the text after it was seen as code. (This is something you should have caught when proofreading your post preview.)

Comment: *"`decltype(iter.key)`"* -- this is always `QWidget*`, regardless of the object to which the key points. `decltype` gives you the **decl**ared **type**, not a dynamic type.

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). ([What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) The approach you have chosen is awkward and probably should be rethought based upon your real goal. Unfortunately, you asked about your approach rather than your real problem, so a helpful answer is unlikely. Why did you define `myMap`? What is the functionality you hope this map will help you achieve?

Comment: FWIW, after speculating on your reason for defining this map, I came up with two alternatives that might fit your reason (neither of which would make `createPerson` a template). However, I lack context to know if either of these actually fit your reason. Plus, they are expressly off-topic as answers here because the question is based upon `createPerson` being a template...

Answer (score 4):

Use a variadic template, with a fold expression:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void func(const T &value)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " --> " << value << '\n';
}

template <typename ...P>
void func_for_each(const P &... values)
{
    (func(values), ...);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    double b = 2.1;
    float c = 3.1f;
    func_for_each(a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the probem here is:   I still need explicitly specify the typename here as oreder, that means I have to know very detail which type should be used, I want to retreve the type dynamicly by program(can we?) seems the complier should know the typename in complier state, but if I have a variable such as  int a;double b;string c;  struct d;  I just stored the a,b,c,d  firstly in a vectore, then the complier should have know the type in complier phase, right?  so why we still couldn't do like this? anything like typeid() or decltype() all invalid.

Comment: @SBHK the type can be deduced, but then you need something to deduce it from. You should add some actual code in your question. What you describe will fail before deducing a type, because a vector cannot hold `int`, `double` and `string` at the same time, unless you use `variant` or similar...

Comment: @SBHK You should've mentioned those variables in the question. See edit. Is this what you want?

Comment: @SBHK C++ is a statically typed language. Types of all variables and expressions are known statically, that is at compile time. You cannot store a, b, c, d in a vector if the types of a, b, c and d are different. It isn't clear what kind of program you are trying to write. Can you state the requirements without referring to C++-specific terminology or techniques such as templates?

Comment: below is my question:

Comment: //define the type and it's argument

struct Argument
{
    char* name;
 int age;
 double height;
}
struct typeAndArg
{
 QWidget *instance;
 Argument args;
}

template<class T>
createPerson(Argument arg)
{
//an API which do similiar case but only the typename T is differnt, the argument can also be specify according to //differnt type
    ....
    T* w = new T(arg.name,arg.age,arg.height);
    .....
    return w;
};

Comment: main()
{
 QMap<QWidget*,Argument> myMap;
 QPushButton a;
 QCheckBox b;
 QLineEdit c;
 
 myMap[&a] = Argument("me", 18, 111.11);
 myMap[&b] = Argument("you", 25, 222.22);
 myMap[&c] = Argument("him", 67, 333.33);
 
 //the key question is here: I want to use a single for loop to do all the things in one line, don't want to //specify typename always, because the map maybe very long, I don't want to call the API mutiple times
 for(auto iter = myMap.begin();iter != myMap.end(); ++iter){
  createPerson<decltype(iter.key()>(iter.value()) //  <------ can we just do it like this?
 } 
}

Comment: sorry, first time use stack overflow, the format couldn't return new line

Comment: @SBHK Edit this information into the question, there you can format it properly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat    edited for my question, simly to say, I want to specify the type name and it's argument both dynamiclly ,your answer for the variadic template is not available for this situation since the int ,double are all simple type, I'm using customrized class for typename, typically, type name is a class, and the argument is it's contrucotor argument, the template function do the same thing for all the new created class so I don't want to care which class it is, I don't care it's order and real type, just let the template recognize it, so no explicit class name assigned,can we?

Comment: @SBHK *"customrized class for typename"* Why is it not in the question? `iter.key` which you're trying to `decltype` appears to be `QWidget *`, not some custom typename class. Please read about [mcve] and provide one. Ideally we want a piece of code we can plop directly into a compiler and start experimenting - no typos, no dependency on Qt, and all that.

Comment: Ultimately, this is going to boil down to adding a function pointer to your typename class, which runs the function on the correct type when executed. You're going to be setting it in your template constructor. Can't help more than this without a minimal example.

Comment: the QWidget* is a class not the int, double, it say customerized class, it can be any struct, don't care what it ,I just want to store this infomration in predefined std::map and the the program pick all the informaton and then call the template funcion. such as ,using the typenae inforamtion for the <  > part, and fill (  ) part with argument, is that enough clear?

Comment: @SBHK No, this is not enough. Show your "custom class for typename".

Comment: it is just a QWidget* ,you can just simply think it. but you know, the QPushButton, QLabel, all the chlild class are derived from QWidget, it is a parent class, so if I have so many subtypes, they are need be recognized by the template , that is what I need.

Comment: @SBHK Create a map with `std::type_index` as key and function pointers as values. Instead of `decltype(iter.key)`, use `typeid(*iter.key())` to search for the correct function in the map. Use the code like in my answer to fill the map with correct functions.